# PC crashes after a few minutes of watching video

Tags: graphics-card, crash, fan, video-streaming, overheating

I have a Dell ST2320L_HDMI monitor and a ATI Radeon HD 4600 Series.   The PC itself is a Dell Inspiron 530S.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium.   The Device Manager says my current driver for the video card is up to date.

Comment: If possible, you should temporarily swap your graphics card with another graphics card, and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried rolling back your video driver to the previous version?

Comment: Have you examined the Event Viewer to see what program crashed, or what Windows has to say about the crash?  Is it the same video (will it run fine with a different video)?  Is it the same player (does it crash with Windows Media Player, but run fine with VLC)?  How long has this been happening?  Were there any changes to the system before this started happening?

Comment: I just recreated the crash and looked at the event viewer afterwards.  It looks like the system is shutting down due to the graphics card overheating.  og Name:      System
Source:        amdkmdag
Date:          4/15/2013 8:38:42 AM
Event ID:      6145
Task Category: POWERPLAY
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic

Comment: Bon Gart's answer is the one that I wanted to select as the answer but somehow "karel's" got selected.   Since I'm a newbie it doesn't look like I can correct this.

Comment: @Bon Gart post your comment as an answer and OP will select it

Comment: The fan is not working on the Video Card.   I removed the card and used air to clean it thoroughly but that did not help.   The fan has a part number of z1053s-3 which doesn't bring up anything on Google.   Should the fan be replaceable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you examined the Event Viewer to see what program crashed, or what Windows has to say about the crash? Is it the same video (will it run fine with a different video)? Is it the same player (does it crash with Windows Media Player, but run fine with VLC)? How long has this been happening? Were there any changes to the system before this started happening?

In short, see what Windows has to tell you about why this is happening.

Comment: The fan is not working on the Video Card. I removed the card and used air to clean it thoroughly but that did not help. The fan has a part number of z1053s-3 which doesn't bring up anything on Google. Should the fan be replaceable?